# How to selectively grep?

Tags: shell, scripting, sed, awk, grep

I have a file that's structured as follows:

```
particle 1
0.1   0.988
0.2   0.975
0.2   0.945
0.3   0.900
...
...
particle 2
0.1   0.988
0.2   0.965
0.2   0.945
0.2   0.935
0.3   0.900
...
```

How do I `grep` only the first occurrence of `0.2` under each particle? e.g I want to `grep` something like

```
particle 1
0.2 0.975
particle 2
0.2 0.965
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @RahulTripathi `-m 1` will make grep match only once.. I don't think your grep line will do what OP wanted.

Comment: @Kent:- Got that!!! Thanks for correcting me as well!!!

Answer (score 6):

this awk one-liner could help:

```
awk '/particle/{print;p=1}p&&/^0\.2/{print;p=0}' file
```

add a test:

```
kent$  cat f
particle 1
0.1 0.988
0.2 0.975
0.2 0.945
0.3 0.900
.....
.....
particle 2
0.1 0.988
0.2 0.965
0.2 0.945
0.2 0.935
0.3 0.900

kent$  awk '/particle/{print;p=1}p&&/^0\.2/{print;p=0}' f
particle 1
0.2 0.975
particle 2
0.2 0.965
```

Answer (score 0):

how about grep

```
grep -E '^partice|^.2' f
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/particle/b;/^0\.2/!d;:a;$!N;/^(0\.2\s).*\n\1/s/\n.*//;ta;P;D' file
```

If the line contains `particle` print it. If the line doesn't start `0.2` delete it. Delete the second line if it begins `0.2` otherwise print the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to print the particle id when there is a 0.2 under it and that the particle ids in your sample input are placeholders but do start with non-digits in your real file:

```
$ cat file
particle 1
0.1   0.988
0.2   0.975
0.2   0.945
0.3   0.900
...
particle 2
0.1   0.988
0.3   0.900
0.4   0.900
...
particle 3
0.1   0.988
0.2   0.965
0.2   0.945
0.2   0.935
0.3   0.900
...

$ awk '/^[^[:digit:]]/{p=$0} p && ($1==0.2){ print p ORS $0; p="" }' file
particle 1
0.2   0.975
particle 3
0.2   0.965
```